# Symfony 4 - Object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation in Profiler only

Tags: php, symfony

The problem only appears in the debug toolbar.

Here is the code I suspect cause the problem

```
/**
   * @Route("/{category_slug}/{slug}", name="content_show")
   * @ParamConverter("content", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
   * @ParamConverter("category", options={"mapping": {"category_slug": "slug"}})
   * @Method("GET")
   */
  public function show(Category $category, Content $content): Response
  {
    $contents = $category->getContents();
    return $this->render('content/show.html.twig', array(
      'category' => $category,
      'list' => $contents,
      'content' => $content,
    ));
  }
```

It is the only part with ParamConverter, and the only modified part before the error.

The page display properly, everything is found, bug the debug toolbar doesn't work anymore with the message :

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Open the web profiler.
```

And inside :

```
App\Entity\Content object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.
```

With a NotFoundHttpException

I cleared the cache, nothing changed.
The code still works, but no toolbar is a pain and I can't figure what is causing this..

I tried with other annotations like :

```
  /**
    * @Route("/{category_slug}/{slug}", name="content_show")
    * @ParamConverter("category", class="App\Entity\Category", options={"mapping": {"category_slug": "slug"}})
    * @Method("GET")
    */
```

Etc..
The only difference is, if I remove content from paramconverter, it still works, but the error is on Category.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: PHP 7.1.9
Composer json :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^4.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/security-csrf": "^4.0",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
},
```

Comment: My bad, just a problem with the route.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a lot of errors online related to yours and I also ran into it, I was using CRUD and my url was matching with one of the previous routes.

I just find that this command `php bin/console router:match url`
helped me by giving me what route is it used and how it has matched.
I think this is really useful and should be shared.